# Positive-definiteness of radial sinc function in three dimensions

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform, positivity

In dimension one, it is well known that $\mathcal{F}\chi_{(-1,1)}=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$. This implies, in particular, that $\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ is a definite positive function. I wonder if a similar result holds in dimension three. Moreover, it would be nice to actually get strictly positive definiteness. So my question is:

**Is it true that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{\sin{|x|}}{|x|}$ is the Fourier transform of a positive (or at least non-negative) function?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s the Fourier transform of the rotation-invariant probability [measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149692/fourier-transform-of-the-unit-sphere) on the unit sphere, and as such is positive definite.

Strict positive definiteness also holds, by the theorem in zu Castell, Filbir and Szwarc ([2005](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2186952)).

Comment: Would you say what $J_\nu$ is (just a keyword, searchable)?

Comment: I just mean that I would be able to understand the post (by yourself) you link at, if you give the name/definition of the function $J_\nu$ ("Bessel function" or so).

Comment: @YCor Oh! I see. I thought it’d be enough that formula (3) there has the required $\frac{\sin|x|}{|x|}$.

Comment: It's enough stricto sensu, but I'd be happy to understand the more general result, so as to grasp some intuition.