# Is $\frac{\sin |\xi|}{|\xi|}$ in range of Fourier Transform for $n \ge 3$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Does there exist $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ s.t., $\displaystyle \widehat{f}(\xi) =  \frac{\sin |\xi|}{|\xi|}$ in case of dimension $n \ge 3$?

It is known that for $n = 2$, the function $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\chi_{\{|x| < 1\}}}{\sqrt{1-|x|^2}}$ curiously has some constant multiple of $\dfrac{\sin |\xi|}{|\xi|}$ as Fourier transform. Or at least is there a way of finding the Fourier transform $\frac{\sin |\xi|}{|\xi|}$ in sense of tempered distributions for $n \ge 3$?

Comment: For $n=3$, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315536/

Comment: Just to expand very slightly on @YCor's comment/answer: because the Fourier transform is injective from $M({\bf R}^n)$ to $C_b({\bf R}^n)$, there is no $f\in L^1({\bf R}^3)$ with the properties that you desire, but instead you need to take the Fourier transform of a certain probability measure that is singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on ${\bf R}^3$.

Comment: There is of course a (radial) distribution that has the desired FT, by Fourier inversion. The only meaningful question you can ask along these lines is how much regularity this distribution has.

Comment: Check Volume 1 of  Gelfand and Shilov's book *Generalized functions*.  You will find  and explicit description of a distribution, concentrated  along the unit sphere, whose  Fourier transform is $(\sin|\xi|)/|\xi|$

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Gelfand and Shilov's book covers the $n = 2m+3$ case. How'd we argue for the even dimensions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a formula  from Duistermaat and Kolk  book *Distributions: Theory and Applications*, Chapter 17, Eq, (17.13). We denote by $\newcommand{\eF}{\mathscr{F}}$ $\eF$ the Fourier transform. Then $\newcommand{\ii}{\boldsymbol{i}}$ $\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}$

$$
\eF^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{\ii t\Vert \xi\Vert}}{\Vert\xi\Vert}\right)=p_n\lim_{\ve\searrow 0} \Big(\; \Vert x\Vert^2-(t+\ve\ii)^2\;\Big)^{-\frac{n-1}{2}},
$$
where $p_n$ is a certain universal constant,

$$p_n=\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{n+1}{2}\big)}{(n-1)\pi^{(n+1)/2}}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.