# Moment generating function of random unit vector

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions, inequalities, harmonic-analysis

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$. Is there any result concerning the calculation or bound (particularly lower bound) of
$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(X^Tv)]$$
for any $v$?

Comment: Because of the symmetry of the distribution of $X$ the problem is equivalent to determine the function $t \to \mathbb{E}e^{t \cdot X_1}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Of course this does not solve the original problem.

Comment: Since $X^T v = |v| (2 B - 1)$, where $B$ has beta distribution with parameters $(\tfrac{n}{2},  \tfrac{n}{2})$, your problem is equivalent to finding the moment generating function of the beta distribution. If I remember correctly, this is some kind of hypergeometric function; certainly this is well-studied.

Comment: Together with https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/beta-distribution this problem seems to be solved.

Comment: Thank you both! BTW, the beta distribution should be with parameter $(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2})$ right?

Comment: Yes. Especially for $n = 3$ you have $Be(1,1)$, the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

As Dieter said, this amounts to the function $t\mapsto \mathbb{E}\ e^{tX_1}$. However, instead of $t\in\mathbb{R}$, it is better to look at it with $t\in\mathbb{C}$ since this is an entire analytic function. So modulo replacing $t$ by $it$, this is the same as the Fourier transform of a sphere which is very well known and expressible in terms of Bessel functions.

See the discussion on this MO question: [Fourier transform of the unit sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149692/fourier-transform-of-the-unit-sphere)