# How to compute the following integral of exponential function over an unit ball

Tags: integration

I want to compute the value of the following integral:
$$\int_{r\in\mathbb{R}^d: \|\|r\|\|\le 1} \exp(a^Tr)dr$$.

In particular, $a$ is the coefficient and the norm $\|\|\cdot\|\|$ could be the general norm function instead of $2$-norm.

Comment: For the 2-norm this is answered (in cyrillic) in Dima Pasechnik’s answer to [this question](//mathoverflow.net/questions/149692/fourier-transform-of-the-unit-sphere). For general norm, no idea.

Comment: the $L_1$ norm result is given here https://mathoverflow.net/a/416254/11260 --- perhaps that calculation can be adapted to $L_p$ norms, something to check.